# Find least value of $9\tan\phi+4\cot\phi+3$ without derivatives

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

The problem is as follows:

> In a pharmaceutical lab in Daegu, a group of scientists need to find
> the power of a visible blue light lamp to get through a sucrose
> crystal in order to measure its purity for a certain medication.
>
> The power for such light is given by:
>
> $$J=\frac{1}{H}$$
>
> Assuming that $H$ has to be the minimum value of the equation from
> below:
>
> $$H=9\tan\phi+4\cot\phi+3$$
>
> $\theta$ is an acute angle which lies in the first quadrant.
>
> What would be the value of $J$ so that the scientists could set up
> their lamp?

The alternatives given in my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\frac{1}{5}\\
2.&\textrm{1}\\
3.&\textrm{15}\\
4.&\frac{1}{15}\\
\end{array}$

This problem is making me feel confused. Should derivatives be used here?

I've attempted to do so and derivate the equation, by doing so this yields:

$H'=9\sec^2\phi-4\csc^2\phi$

But equating this to zero doesn't seem to be the intended approach.

Then I came up with the idea of adding the intervals from where $\phi$ in the first quadrant lies.

$0\leq \cot \phi < +\infty$

Tangent is also in the same interval:

$0\leq \tan \phi < +\infty$

Then multiplying by $9$ and by $4$ and adding $3$ to the second equation.

This results into:

$3\leq 9\tan\phi+4\cot\phi+3 < +\infty$

**But without any further constrain there isn't any way to tell, which would be the least value?**

If it would had been the integer value, wouldn't had been $4$?

Running out of idead, what it came to my mind was to equate both functions:

$\tan\phi=\cot\phi$

This corresponds to $\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Assuming this: *I'm guessing that the result would be*

$9\tan\phi=1$

$4\cot\phi=1$

then $1+1+3=5$

But this is more like guessing and not a serious way to justify the answer. I cannot be sure if that's the answer. Can someone help me here and **explain me why derivatives doesn't seem to work?**

**How to solve this without derivative?**. Help me please, I'm confused.

Comment: If $\tan\theta=x$, then $\cot\theta=\frac1x$.  As you do not need to solve for $\theta$, you could simply use the substitution and find the minimum using quadratics.

Answer (score 3):

Note

\begin{align}
9\tan\phi+4\cot\phi+3&=( 9\tan\phi+4\cot\phi-12)+15\\
&=(3\sqrt{\tan \phi}- 2\sqrt{\cot \phi})^2+15\ge 15
\end{align}

Comment: That's an interesting approach. But I'm assuming that the intended strategy was to use $b^2 \geq 0$. What's the justification of the method you have used?. Other user has hinted that what's used here is Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but upong reading such entry on wikipedia it expresses it in terms of vectors, and I don't see any vectors here. **What property or identity have you used, does it has a name?**. I attempted to do you method but you used $\left(3\sqrt{\tan\phi}-2\sqrt{\cot\phi}\right)^2$ intead of $\left(3\sqrt{\tan\phi}+2\sqrt{\cot\phi}\right)^2$. Why the later doesn't work?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell - you could do the latter. Then, you have to show its least value is 24 instead of 0, which is less convenient

Comment: Can you please add this second method in your answer?. I'm trying to do it on my own but I can't get the same as you. Please?. Can you please attend my earlier doubt?. Does your method has a name?. **Why its least value has to be $24$ intead of $0$ this part I don't understand?** Please explain this to me. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Using drivatives works fine.

$H' = 9\sec^2\phi - 4\csc^2\phi =0\\
9\sin^2\phi = 4\cos^2\phi\\
\tan^2\phi = \frac {4}{9}\\
\phi = \arctan {\frac 23}$

Plugging this into the original equation gives:

$9(\frac 23) + 4(\frac 32) + 3 = 15$

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2 = \tan \phi$
$$ 0 \leq \left(3x - \frac{2}{x} \right)^2 = 9 x^2 - 12 + \frac{4}{x^2}  $$

$$ 12 \leq   9 x^2  + \frac{4}{x^2}  $$
$$ 12 \leq   9 \tan \phi + 4 \cot \phi $$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: Howdy!. Interesting approach. I tried to understand the wikipedia entry you had just written. But it seems too complex for me. But from what I do understand in your method you seem to use $b^2\geq 0$. While the inequality you mention indicates the use of vectors. The article also mentions the dot is the inner product. What it confuses me the most is **how does this inequality explains your method?** You used a greater and equal than zero not less and equal as the inequality. Can you please explain this part? I'm assuming that the final part in your answer is to add $3$ to both sides.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late this answer but I think worth mentioning it.

It is just AM-GM - the inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean:

For $\theta \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right)$ you have $\tan \theta >0$ and AM-GM gives
$$9\tan \theta + 4\frac 1{\tan \theta}+3 \stackrel{AM-GM}{\geq} 2\sqrt{9\tan \theta \cdot 4\frac 1{\tan \theta}}+3 = 12+3 = 15$$

The minimum is reached for
$$9\tan \theta = 4\frac 1{\tan \theta} \stackrel{\theta \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right)}{\Leftrightarrow} \theta = \arctan \frac 23$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $\tan\phi=z$

$f(z)=9 z + \frac{4}{z} + 3$ is minimum when $f'(z)=0$ and $f''(z)>0$

$f'(z)=9 -\frac{4}{z^2}=0\to z=\pm\frac{2}{3}$.

$f''(z)=\frac{8}{z^3}$

as $f''\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)>0$ we have that $f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=15$ is the minimum.